# Perform wildcard search of all (displayed) model fields in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC5 View where I am using the Grid.MVC component (https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/). This allows me to easily display data from my Oracle DB and has out of the box functionality for Sorting/Filtering each Data Column. What I am trying to implement now is a Wildcard Search across all fields in my grid. For example, if I search the number "2" I'd like to return all records that contain a "2" be they string, decimal, or DateTime.

The filter capability on this grid performs filtering (for individual columns) partially by modifying the URL (http://homeURL/?grid-filter=Location.DEPT__1__accounting) such as 1 being `Equals`, 2 being `Contains`, 3 being `StartsWith`, and 4 being `EndsWith` and then after the next 2 underscores being the search criteria.

I first thought I was going down the right path by using JavaScript to modify to the desired URL via daisy-chaining all fields with the search criteria using a CONTAINS. I then noticed that `decimal` fields like [Cost] and `DateTime` (Oracle DB) fields like [Acquired_Date] have criteria settings of `Equals, Greater Than, and Less Than`, so I tried:

```
$('#SearchIcon').on("click", function (e) {
            window.location = window.location.href.substr(0, window.location.href.indexOf('?'));
            window.location = "?grid-filter=FIELD1__2__" + document.getElementById("Search").value +
                              "&grid-filter=FIELD2__2__" + document.getElementById("Search").value +
                              "&grid-filter=COST__1__" + document.getElementById("Search").value +
                              // etc. -- ALL FIELDS
                              "&grid-filter=NOTE__2__" + document.getElementById("Search").value;
        });
```

This technically functions, but with the `[&]` is searching for a record(s) that have the corresponding search criteria in EVERY field. What I need is something similar, but with an OR `[||]` conditioning ---- unfortunately the grid component does not contain this form of functionality.

I then thought to pass the search criteria to a controller action and use it via a multi-WHERE clause and return only the records fitting the filter to my View:

```
public ActionResult SearchAssets(string searchCriteria)
        { 
            fillPagingIntervalList();
            var assetSearchResults = db.ENTITY_COLLECTION.Where(m => m.ID.ToString() == searchCriteria ||
            m.Model.ToString() == searchCriteria ||
            m.COST.ToString() == searchCriteria ||
            // etc. -- ALL FIELDS
            ).FirstOrDefault();
            var assetCount = db.ENTITY_COLLECTION.ToList().Count();
            return View(assetSearchResults);
        }
```

This resulted in an error with the WHERE cluase, stating to view the `Inner Exception` for details -- `ORA-12704: character set mismatch MVC`. I then reduced my multiple conditions down to just 2 fields to be searched for debugging:

```
var assetSearchResults = db.ENTITY_COLLECTION.Where(m => m.ID.ToString() == searchCriteria ||
            m.Model.ToString() == searchCriteria).FirstOrDefault();
```

Resulting in:
EntityCommandExecutionException was unhandled by user code.

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.

Inner Exception: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got NCLOB
```

Anyone have an idea on how to get what I want working? I also tried `.Where(...con1...).Where(...con2...).Where(...etc...)` with the same error resulting. I figured a wildcard search across all fields would be difficult to implement, but this is proving to be a whole bigger animal than I anticipated.

Comment: Looks like a poor implementation by Oracle.  Your query appears like it would work just fine on SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be very slow, but try this, which will load the entire collection into objects and let LINQ do the filtering on the client side:

```
public ActionResult SearchAssets(string searchCriteria)
    { 
        fillPagingIntervalList();
        var assetSearchResults = db.ENTITY_COLLECTION.ToList().Where(m => m.ID.ToString() == searchCriteria ||
        m.Model.ToString() == searchCriteria ||
        m.COST.ToString() == searchCriteria ||
        // etc. -- ALL FIELDS
        ).FirstOrDefault();
        var assetCount = db.ENTITY_COLLECTION.ToList().Count();
        return View(assetSearchResults);
    }
```

You could try something like this:

```
public ActionResult SearchAssets(string searchCriteria)
    { 
        fillPagingIntervalList();
        var assetSearchResults = db.ENTITY_COLLECTION.Where(m => m.ID.ToString() == searchCriteria)
        .Union(db.ENTITY_COLLECTION.Where(m =>m.Model.ToString()==searchCriteria))
        .Union(db.ENTITY_COLLECTION.Where(m =>m.COST.ToString() == searchCriteria))
        // etc. -- ALL FIELDS
        var assetCount = db.ENTITY_COLLECTION.ToList().Count();
        return View(assetSearchResults);
    }
```

Although, ultimately I would suggest looking into something like a predicate builder.  Seems to be what you are doing anyhow.

Comment: Ah, `.Union` is what I was originally looking for with my attempt in the Controller! I've changed it now, but with an issue: `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[Project.DAL.ENTITY_COLLECTION]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Project.DAL.ENTITY_COLLECTION]'.` My View I'm returning the filtered collection to expects a List: `@model List<Project.DAL.ENTITY_COLLECTION>`. When I add `.ToList()` after the last `.Union()` I get the previous error of `expected - got NCLOB`...?

Comment: When I attempt the slower method of `.ToList().Where(... || .... ||.... etc.)` I receive `An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in InventoryTracker.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`, which I believe is due to several of my fields containing null values.

Comment: I then tried checking each for `null` (ex.) `m.MODEL_ID != null && m.MODEL_ID.ToString() == searchCriteria ||`, but now receive: `An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ENTITY_COLLECTION_E8B1D181BBB88B9C34D87212BA68486F709960DF8F42CAA9028631D5037F93F5', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[Project.DAL.ENTITY_COLLECTION]'.`

Comment: The last error seems like you need to call .ToList() before passing it into the view.

Comment: The last one about `DynamicProxies`? Why would I need to call `.ToList()` again when I already have it as `db.ENTITY_COLLECTION.ToList().Where(..... || ..... || .... etc).FirstOrDefault();`? As is when I go to my last line of code `return View(assetSearchResults);` and attempt to add `.ToList()` intellisense shows the only `To` option as being `ToString()`.

Comment: I don't think you want `.FirstOrDefault()` unless you only wanted one record returned.  Your view seems to want a List of records.  Try `db.ENTITY_COLLECTION.ToList().Where(..... || ..... || .... etc).ToList();`  You need a second ToList, because I don't believe Where returns a List, just an IEnumerable or IQueryable. And your view is asking explicitly for a `List<Project.DAL.ENTITY_COLLECTION>`

Comment: I see your point there. Everything appears to be flowing fine through my controller now with the second `.ToList()`, but oddly when I hit `return View(assetSearchResults);` and continue through Debug, nothing happens. The same Home/Index view is still in place along with my original search criteria in the search box. Same amount of records and everything.

Comment: Scratch that. I think I was mixing up with some View code I had copy/pasted from a separate View; all working now. Thanks so much for your help! You wouldn't happen to have any thoughts on a separate issue would you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30710776/return-to-second-to-last-url-in-mvc-return-view-with-previous-filter-conditions